# Find number of close loops in Binary Edge Image

Tags: python, image, opencv, hough-transform

I have a binary image with the number of close loops and free curves like shown in image..
[image]

My approach so far- (python code):

- Skeletonize the image to get edge of 1 pixel
- Use label/bwlabel to get individual curve/edge
- Applied DFS to get the edge which is not close
- Apply DFS to get close edge..but not working correctly..

**Expected output** -

Number of close loops =6, the sum of the pixels along the loop or all (x,y) points along the edge of the close curve as highlighted in **RED**

[image]

Expected Output-

Comment: I'd invert the image and count the connected components. If you're using OpenCV, you should add the [tag:opencv] tag. The [tag:processing] tag is for the Processing programming language and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a binary image: simply use [`findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) to get the inner contours.

Bare in mind you want use [`cv2.RETR_CCOMP` as the Countour Retrieval Mode](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71) to easily access the holes:

> retrieves all of the contours and organizes them into a two-level hierarchy. At the top level, there are external boundaries of the components. At the second level, there are boundaries of the holes. If there is another contour inside a hole of a connected component, it is still put at the top level.

It should be a matter of simply getting the length of countours on the second level (holes)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input as grayscale
- Threshold to binary
- Get the contours and hierarchy
- Loop over the contours and corresponding hierarchy and discard contours with no parent (the external ones) and save and count the contours with no children (the innermost ones)
- Draw the contours on the input
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('loops.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
hh, ww = img.shape

# blacken right columns that are white
img[0:hh, ww-3:ww] = 0

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hierarchy = contours[1] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[2]
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions
hierarchy = hierarchy[0]

# count inner contours
count = 0
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.merge([result,result,result])
for component in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    cntr = component[0]
    hier = component[1]
    # discard outermost no parent contours and keep innermost no child contours
    # hier = indices for next, previous, child, parent
    # no parent or no child indicated by negative values
    if (hier[3] > -1) & (hier[2] < 0):
        count = count + 1
        cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 2)

# print count
print("count:",count)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("loops_result.png",result)

# show result   
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting contours:

[image]

Count:

```
count: 6
```